# Passing data between two Netty Server Pipelines

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I have two Netty TCP Server sockets and I have clients connecting both the sockets. My requirement is to get the data from one client do some data transformation and send it to the other server so that it can write it to all its clients. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this in Netty? If yes, any pointers on what I should look at will be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Sarz. I did try that but couldn't find what I was looking for. Hence the post here. Didn't realize folks just down vote questions here.

Comment: What you did you do so far? did you manage TCP client/server connection so far?

Comment: I have two servers (say A, B). One client each connects to each of these servers. Say Client X connects to Server A and Client Y connects to Server B. Now, X writes data to A which I want to pass it to Server B so that Server B can write it to Client Y.
Basically, I have X -> A (==>) B -> Y. I have the client to server part done. Wanted to know I can write data from Server A to Server B. Do I need to it do it by getting the B->Y channel or can I do it a generic way such that everyone connected to B will get the data?

Comment: Write a client in server A's thread which connects server B and send required that and same as server B to A

Comment: If the client in Server A (lets call it F) connects to Server B and now if A wants to send data to B through F, it writes data to F and that in turn sends the data to B. Now B has gets the data and wants to write it to all clients connected to it (which will then include F as well)? So F will receive the data that it send to B and then send it back to B and thus will engage in an infinite loop?

Comment: this seems there are alot of things in your mind but you did not write in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical system integration task. Search for integration tools like
[Apache camel](http://camel.apache.org)